# Android User Preferences Error

Tags: java, android, user-preferences

I am getting the following error thrown from the code below. It seems to run happily on a virtual device but as soon at I run it on a real device it crashes.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                               at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:223)

Here is the code of the function that seems to throw the error.

```
 public void queueJump2() {



        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("settings");
        query.getInBackground("BauCSafDjA", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {


                    String queueJumpActive = object.getString("status");

                    Log.i("QUEUE JUMP STATUS >>",queueJumpActive);


                    if (!queueJumpActive.equals("active")){

                        Button qjumpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.qjumpButton);
                        qjumpButton.setText("DISABLED");

                    } else {



                        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                        String ts = tsLong.toString();

                        Long dayAgoLong = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)-84600;
                        String dayAgo = dayAgoLong.toString();

                        Log.i("Current Time Stamp: ",  ts.toString());
                        Log.i("dayAgo >>: ",  dayAgo.toString());

                        Date dNow = new Date( );
                        SimpleDateFormat ft =
                                new SimpleDateFormat ("HH");

                        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
                        boolean inDs = tz.inDaylightTime(new Date());

if (String.valueOf(inDs) == "false") {
```

Comment: Which line of code does cause the crash exactly?

Comment: String queueJumpActive = object.getString("status"); - thats line 223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be adding an integer to sharedpreference and trying to get it as a string. Try adding your string "status" this way.

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("status",string.valueof(YOUR STATUS INTEGR));
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I uninstalled the application from the device, it seemed that there may have been something stored in the preferences that shouldn't have been. thanks!